# Chart js horizontal bar: Not all labels are showing on Y axis

Tags: chart.js

When I have about 600 bars on my chart, many labels on the Y axis are skipped, even when I make the font smaller and even if I'm showing each label on a single line. I would like to show all the labels even when there are so many that they overlap. Is that possible? The screenshot has only 100 bars but with 600 or 700 bars many labels get skipped.
[image: Working sample of 100 bars]

I have tried turning autoSkip to false and stepSize to 1 with no avail.
y: {
ticks: {
autoSkip: false,
stepSize: 1,
font: {
size: 6
},

Answer (score 0):

I had stepSize spelled stepsize. It's working now.